# Delete from CHANGETABLE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have just enabled the use of change tracking within my database. I'm using these changes to update an index every couple minutes. The program is fetching the information from the `changetable` correctly simply using

`SELECT FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.table,0)`

I now need to purge the table and `delete` any existing records.

Thanks

Comment: And what is the problem/question?

Comment: how do i delete from the CHANGETABLE. bearing in mind it doesn't really exist. sql server creates it but its not a visible table in the database. I can select from changetable but not delete from changetable. it tells me the table doesnt exist when i try to delete

Answer (score 1):

Disable change tracking for the tanbe (dbo.table) and then re-enable

Answer (score 0):

Create a job to delete when records are greater than 0

DELETE FROM "tablename" WHERE RECORDS > 0

or

DELETE * FROM "tablename" WHERE RECORDS > 0

Comment: The only problem with this is i have no idea what the table is called. I can SELECT FROM CHANGETABLE without a problem. but DELETE FROM CHANGETABLE gives "Invalid object name 'CHANGETABLE'."

Answer (score 0):

You don't purge records from CHANGETABLE, it is managed by SQL for each database using the `CHANGE_RETENTION` and `AUTO_CLEANUP` options when it was turned on. You can read about those  options at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964713.aspx).

In your call to CHANGETABLE, you should change the second argument (the "0") to the last `SYS_CHANGE_VERSION` that you received, and then you will only receive the records that have been modified past that version.

Answer (score 0):

You can purge a change tracking table by disabling and enabling the change tracking for that particular table:

```
ALTER TABLE Attributes DISABLE CHANGE_TRACKING
ALTER TABLE Attributes ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = OFF)
```